# Loop displays current page

Tags: loop

I want to display a loop in my page-projets.php file.

```
<div class="loop center">

    <?php       
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part('content');
        endwhile;
        get_template_part('pagination');
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

However, on the resulting page, I can only see the page itself within the loop. Sometimes, it even returns a blank result : http://riehling.mrcoolblog.com/projets/

Could you please tell me what's wrong here ?

Regards,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

All other things being equal, your page file "page-projets.php" will display a page with a slug = "projets". So... what is the contents of that page?

Comment: That page just displays a loop. "Projets" is the term for "post" in this project, so basically this is the main loop for the website.

Comment: Well then, shouldn't your file be "single-projets.php" rather than "page-projets.php.php".

Comment: Sorry, I have been confusing you. A "Projet" is a page following the single.php template, indeed. The "Projets" page is the main loop, displaying all projects.

Answer (score 0):

To display a custom list of post types, you would have to write your own loop in the your page-projets.php theme file.

For example:

```
<div class="loop center">

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => '',
        'posts_per_page'    => '',
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('content');
        endwhile;
        get_template_part('pagination');
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

Replace the values for **post_type** and **posts_per_page** with your custom values.

You can also find additional parameters in the Wordpress Codex for **[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)**

Comment: OK, thank you.
I now use the following code :
`$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=>20,
    'paged' => $paged
  );

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( have_posts() ) :
   // while ( have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    get_template_part('content');
   endwhile;
   get_template_part('pagination');
  endif;`

Comment: But, that breaks the pagination. I cannot go to page 2 (no pagination displayed and raw URL ../page/2 sends a 404 ).